# QtQuick drawing shapes and colors but not text

Tags: qt, raspberry-pi, yocto, qtquick2

I've just tried running my qtquick2 application, my application opens successfully but no text is drawn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fonts are probably missing on your target.
You can add them to your layer by appending IMAGE_INSTALL_append with  `ttf-dejavu-sans`, `ttf-ubuntu-mono`, `ttf-ubuntu-sans` or any other font.